# How to Create account popup liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using liferay theme template.

I want to create pop-up for create account form page which currently come as a separate-page.

Below is my code for link of `Sign In` and `Sign Up` page.
Sign in shows pop-up but sign-in page will redirect to page which is for create account.
I wan't to show create account pop-up in the same page.

```html
#if (!$is_signed_in)
    <a class="sign-up1" id="use-dialog" data-redirect="false" href="http://localhost:8080/web/guest/welcome?p_p_id=58&amp;p_p_lifecycle=0&amp;p_p_state=maximized&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;saveLastPath=false&amp;_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Fcreate_account" id="_58_fhhk" role="menuitem">
        <img id="fhhk" src="http://localhost:8080/e-commerce-theme/images/spacer.png" alt="" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/e-commerce-theme/sprite/images/common/_sprite.png'); background-position: 50% -176px; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 16px; width: 16px;">
        <span class="taglib-text " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1420519930077_1070">Sign up</span>
    </a>
#end    
#if (!$is_signed_in)
    |<a class="sign-in" data-redirect="false" href="http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?p_l_id=10858" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1420097083820_231" role="menuitem" title="">
        <span id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1420097083820_865" class="nav-item-label"> Sign In </span>
     </a> 
#end
```

**Environment Used:** Liferay 6.2 bundled with Tomcat

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: i have followed below steps but not succed. i am success in show pop up for LOG IN screen.                                                    http://michi-path.blogspot.ca/2013/05/use-createmy-account-portlet-liferay-61.html

Comment: Provide the code you written

Comment: I have updated my question where I added two link. For sign up and sign in Templates code of theme.

Comment: Have you used any javascript to show the pop-up or are you thinking that giving the span and link would magically create a pop-up for you.